# $1 + \log_2 (n + 1) = n + \cos \frac {n\pi}{6}$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, contest-math

I have encountered this equation in a preparatory test for a contest in Romania.

Solve for every integer $n$:

$$1 + \log_2 (n + 1) = n + \cos \frac {n\pi}{6}$$

I am not sure how to deal with it. I tried trying to find some values and try to establish some orders regarding those values but did not find success. Of course, one of the solution is 0, but that is all I can find.

Comment: first of all, $n-2$ is larger than $\log_2(n+1)$ definitively in $n$, so you need to test only few cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n+1$ must be positive since we use it in a logarithm. So
we have that $n \geq 0$. Now we have
$$ 1 + \log_2(n+1) = n + \cos(n\pi/6) $$
$$ \geq n - 1$$

So we can rearrange to get $2^n \leq 4n+4$, so it must be that $n \leq 4$, and we can manually check from here that the only solutions are $n=0$ and $n=3$.